# How to send array via email?

Tags: php

I have problem to send array from database via email. I´m sure may people have got the same problem. I don´t know how to explain more but here is some script.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tb_xxx WHERE id_prd = '$ref_id_prd'";

        $result=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql);
        while ($rs=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $ref_id_prd=$rs[ref_id_prd];
                        $prd=$rs[prd];
                        $price=$rs[price];

text="$prd <br>$price";
}


$recipient = $iemail;
$subject = "my subject";

$headers = "From: xxx@xxx.com \n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: xxx@xxx.com \n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 \n";


   $msg = $text;

   mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: write the vars in to a string, send the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to accumulate all the array values into a single string for the message body.

```
$text = "";
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $ref_id_prd=$rs[ref_id_prd];
        $prd=$rs[prd];
        $price=$rs[price];

        // Use .= to append to the current value
        $text .= "$prd <br>$price\n";
}
```

To send it, use `$text` as the message body:

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $text, $headers);
```

Note, you will need to do additional formatting on the line below to get it looking the way you want in your HTML email:

```
$text .= "$prd <br>$price\n";
```

For example, you could make a list of products:

```
$text = "<ul>\n";
// inside the while loop...
$text .= "<li>$prd: $price</li>\n";
// After the loop, close the list
$text .= "</ul>"
```

#### Update: How to build it into an HTML table:

```
$text = "";

// Open the table:
$text .= "<table>\n";
// Table header...
$text .= "<thead><tr><th>Product</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>\n";
// Open the table body
$text .= "<tbody>\n";

while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $ref_id_prd=$rs[ref_id_prd];
        $prd=$rs[prd];
        $price=$rs[price];

        // Build table rows...
        $text .= "<tr><td>$prd</td><td>$price</td></tr>";
}
// Close the table
$text .= "</table>";
```

Comment: Could you tell my how to put it in table ?

Comment: oh good, now I could finish my project by you, thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `$message` variable with `$msg`

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```